# How to create glass with a glowing core in blender?

Tags: materials

I'm a newbie to Blender and would like to create glass objects (rough glass) with a glow coming from the center. For example, you can think of glowing marbles when the glow source is trapped inside the glass.

What's the best approach for creating such an effect in Blender?

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT:* Some missing information I forgot to include: I'm using the Cycles engine, and am aiming at a look similar to this image: http://www.supercoolpets.com/pictures/HA6319blueLight_x.jpg (less texturing on the glass itself perhaps though)

Comment: Please specify what render engine you are using

Comment: Please add a screenshot/image ilustrating what kind of result you want to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicates: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16674/transparent-blue-plastic-material-which-emits-light/16677#16677 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61457/making-glass-orbs-with-effects-inside